# How to return true or false using the input checkbox in react js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My input checkbox always returns true, when i mark it passsa true correctly, but when i unmark tb i get true. I would like the checkbox to return true when checked and false when unchecked, this way I would apply my logic in the handlesubmit function.

```
    handleChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        console.log(name, value);
        switch (name) {

          case 'period': this.json.schedule = 'period'; break;

    }


 <input
       type="checkbox"
       name="period"
       defaultValue
       onChange={this.handleChange}
 />
```

Comment: I added the function on change

Comment: Your `onChange` callback function isnt returning anything, where are you checking for true and false?

Comment: I think I understood the operation of the wrong component, believe that the simple fact of unmarking would return false, instead of true as I'm always receiving.

Comment: add `checked` to `const { name, value } = e.target`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checkout the value of `e.target.checked`.

In your case, change this line: `const { name, value } = e.target` to include `checked`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: true
    }
  }
  
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { checked } = e.target
    this.setState({
      checked: checked
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox"
               onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
               defaultChecked={this.state.checked}/>
        {this.state.checked.toString()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render((<App/>), document.getElementById('testing'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="testing"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use useState.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
    const [Check, setCheck] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{Check ? 'Checked' : 'Not checked'}</h1>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => setCheck(e.target.checked) }/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking wether the box is checked or not, try:

```
handleChange = e => {
    if (document.getElementByClassName("period").checked) {
        // box is checked
    } else {
        // box is unchecked
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the function on change

Comment: Thanks for that, I made an edit as well. I would keep things simple, readability is always important.

Comment: Where would I add this instruction?

Comment: you can use `e.target.checked` instead

Answer (score 0):

You first need to define what check is considered? If it is check it is true and when it is not checked it is false. Here is some code to get you started.

```
{   this.state.data.map(function(item, index) { return (
    <input type="checkbox" checked={item.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, index)}/>
  );
      }.bind(this))
}
```

Comment: I added the function on change